# PHP/SQL how can I combine 2 requests into one

Tags: php, sql

so i have 1 query it makes possible combine 2 rating numbers into one

```
SELECT (SELECT SUM(rating) FROM " . PREFIX . "_post_extras WHERE user_id ='{$row['user_id']}') + (SELECT SUM(rating) FROM " . PREFIX . "_comments WHERE user_id ='{$row['user_id']}') AS rating
```

how do I change my query so that the rating that is in the postextras and in the postcomments was one as in the first request? and to sort by the common rating?

this is my query that i cant to change: there doesnt have rating from table _comments but i need it too.

```
SELECT dle_users.user_id, dle_users.user_group, dle_users.name, dle_users.foto, SUM(dle_post_extras.rating) as rating
    FROM dle_users
    JOIN dle_post_extras ON dle_post_extras.user_id = dle_users.user_id  
    WHERE dle_post_extras.rating > '0'  
    GROUP BY dle_users.user_id
    ORDER BY dle_post_extras.rating
    DESC LIMIT 0,10
```

Comment: Is it needed to do so in SQL? Why not add the numbers in PHP?

Comment: i make list like with while ( $row = $db->get_row() ) { echo $row['rating'] ; }

Comment: Then you probably either need to restructure that code (to gather all ratings in first loops and outputting them later on) or make more complex SQL queries. My experience is that the second one makes your project much more fragile because such queries are less maintainable

Comment: yes i know, i have cache and it will be load only on static site

Comment: That's not what I meant: will you get the meaning behind a complex query if you look at your code in a year? Or will it be easier to read some more lines of PHP that achieve the same result? The performance difference between both solutions should be neglectible